# one word for one who is not really a photographer but with more interest in it?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for a person **with great interest in photography but not really a photographer**? who is an enthusiast for photography or atleast who is going to be one soon?

Comment: An [Ansel Adams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansel_Adams) [wannabe](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=Ansel+Adams+wannabe&oq=Ansel+Adams+wannabe&gs_l=hp.3..0i30.6947.6947.2.7147.1.0.1.0.1.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c._k99tsSVNlo&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=36334d0cbfd23fda&biw=1466&bih=886), perhaps? Quite a lot of people have used that expression on the Internet.

Answer (score 8):

I'd suggest "**shutterbug**."

The [Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shutterbug) defines this informal word as: "*an enthusiastic amateur photographer*."

Comment: Yes, and if OP can stand 2 words, then "*amateur photographer*" itself is quite common.

Answer (score 6):

In a more generic sense, calling them an ***enthusiast*** works nicely. It includes those who are "going to be one soon" (as described in your question), and if you want to step it up to include a much more active participant, you can qualify them as an ***avid enthusiast***.

Comment: And if you wanted to go in the other direction, you could use _hobbyist_ instead of _enthusiast_.

Answer (score 0):

Consider maybe *[semi-pro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-professional)* or *[pro-am](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro%E2%80%93am)*, both originally sport terms that have extended to other fields.

*Semi-pro* would refer more to someone who works as a photographer part-time but that isn't really his main occupation, while *pro-am* would imply a sort of professional-level amateur, an enthusiast who's as good as professionals in his field.

Comment: Prosumer is used by the industry to describe models aimed at high end, but not necessarily professional, users.

Answer (score 0):

There´s the term ¨protog¨ for professional photographers, I´d say ¨amphotog¨ works pretty well for amateur photographer.